# I'm trying to code a binary search tree using c++ but the program takes only 2 inputs and stops

Tags: c++, search, tree, binary

Notice the //, the program stops taking input and that is the main problem. 
`root->cand = data;` 
Here is the full code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;
 struct node
{
    int cand;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};
class candies
{
    node *root;

public:
    candies();
    int add(int);
    int check();
};
candies::candies()
{
    root = NULL;
}
int candies::add(int data)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root->cand = data; //code stops here
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        node *temp = root;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            if (data < temp->cand)
            {
                temp = temp->left;
            }
            else
            {
                temp = temp->right;
            }
        }
        temp = new node;
        temp->cand = data;
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    }
    return 1;
}
int candies::check()
{
    node *temp;
    temp = root;
    int data;
    cin >> data;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (temp->cand == data)
        {
            cout << "YES\n";
            return 1;
        }
        else if (data < temp->cand)
            temp = temp->left;
        else if (data > temp->cand)
            temp = temp->right;
    }
    cout << "NO\n";
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    candies c;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    while (n--)
    {
        int data;
        cin >> data;
        c.add(data);
    }
    c.check();
}
```

Comment: `if (root == NULL){  root->cand = data;` you ensure that it's a null pointer and then you try to access it anyway?

Comment: Please read [why `bits/stdc++.h` should not be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/1782465).

Comment: @hacxter Now after you selected "the best" answer reread my answer.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member function `add` is invalid and moreover has undefined behavior.

In this if statement

```
if (root == NULL)
{
    root->cand = data; //code stops here
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
}
```

there is used a null-pointer to access memory.

In this else statement

```
else
{
    node *temp = root;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (data < temp->cand)
        {
            temp = temp->left;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = temp->right;
        }
    }
    temp = new node;
    temp->cand = data;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
}
```

the created node `temp` is not added to the tree. So the program has a memory leak.

The function can be written the following way. It is better to make its return type `void`. Otherwise the returned value 1 as in your function implementation does not make sense.

```
class candies
{
    node *root;

public:
    candies();
    void add(int);
    int check();
};

//...

void candies::add( int data )
{
    node **current = &root;

    while ( *current != nullptr )
    {
        if ( data < ( *current )->cand )
        {
            current = &( *current )->left;
        }
        else
        {
            current = &( *current )->right;
        }
    }

    *current = new node { data, nullptr, nullptr };
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks way better than mine.

Comment: @hacxter You selected as the best answer an incomplete answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are first checking that root is NULL. If it is, you are changing its data. This is not good at all, and will cause a crash.

```
if (root == NULL)
{
    root->cand = data; //code stops here
```

If root is NULL, you must create a root node first.

```
if ( root == nullptr ) {
    root = new node;
    root->cand = data;
```